# expression engine search result

Tags: expressionengine

I am facing an issue related expression engine search. Links are not correct that search result displays and my pages just getting the header and footer and content is blank to search pages.

```
I want my results in particular format 

**In format**

1.**Result1** ***View detail***

1.**Result2** ***View detail***
```

How would i do that..what should i write on result code and also how would i limit the character limit to result text

[My code  for search results is on this link](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html#var_auto_path)

Comment: Hi Neha.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  There's a dedicated EE Stackoverflow site now.  I suggest you ask your question there. http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/  Also SO works best when you just have one question in each post.

Answer (score 0):

If you links are not correct for your search results it may be that your preferences are not set correctly.

Each channel will have it's own `Search Results URL` preference.  That's where the `{auto_path}`data is pulled from in your example.

Comment: Can you give more detail?  What is the setting in your preference?  What is the actual code you are using?  What is the actual result you are getting?  What is the result you expect?

Comment: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html#var_auto_path

Comment: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html#var_auto_path
This is the link of my code,,,actually i am getting all results included all kind of entries like pages,widgets thats why  links are not working for all results..it works for pages only..but i am getting widgets links also ..There is some condition of {meta_title}...I am not aware of that ..Please help